# view is undefine, loading combo box issue in 4.07

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am occassionally ( usually 1 in 3 page loads) receive the following error message

> view is undefined
>   view.onItemSelect(record);

In my view

```
            {
                xtype:'combobox',
                name:'PurchaseOrderStatusId',
                id:'PurchaseOrderStatusCombo',
                displayField:'Name',
                store:'PurchaseOrderStatuses',
                mode:'local',
                valueField:'Id',
                fieldLabel:'Status',
                width: 350
            },
            {
                xtype:'combobox',
               name:'SupplierId',
               id:'SupplierCombo',
                displayField:'Name',
                store:'Suppliers',
                mode:'local',
                valueField:'Id',
                fieldLabel:'Suppliers',
                width: 350
            },
```

// in my controller
       onLaunch: function () {

```
        var suppliers = this.getSuppliersStore();
        suppliers.load();

        var purchaseOrderStatuses = this.getPurchaseOrderStatusesStore();
        purchaseOrderStatuses.load();

        var purchaseOrdersStore = this.getPurchaseOrdersStore();
        purchaseOrdersStore.load({
            callback: this.onPurchaseOrderLoad,
            scope: this
        });
    },
    onPurchaseOrderLoad: function (selection) {
        var form = Ext.getCmp('purchaseOrderForm');
        form.loadRecord(selection[0]);
    },
```

in my model

```
    {
        mapping:'PurchaseOrderStatusId',
        name:'PurchaseOrderStatusId'
    },       
    {
        mapping:'SupplierId',
        name:'SupplierId'
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. But looking at the pieces of codes - are all your stores remote? If yes, then you need to make sure load operation on all of them finished before you do anything else with items.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how the error message you are reporting is linked to any of the code you have revealed so far. So it's difficult to connect the dots here.

However here are a couple of observations:
1. If you need your stores to always load ASAP when your app launches set the `autoLoad:true` config on those stores. This way you don't have to explicitly load them and they have more time to finish loading before your view is ready to go.
2. If you need to load an instance of your model into the form you can use Model.load method instead of having a store do that for you. You will need to provide API on the model on how to read the records from the server.
3. Model mapping is not necessary if your Model fields match to what the server returns.

If you need further help, please update your question with some more debug info.